# Setting Default Value of Sidebar in a Web Site to Closed

Tags: javascript, html

I took this HTML template;

> https://html5up.net/editorial

And made some changes on it. I tried to set default value of sidebar-menu which is on the left- closed so that it will be hidden when people visit the web site.

I change this code;

```
// Sidebar.
var $sidebar = $('#sidebar'),
$sidebar_inner = $sidebar.children('.inner');

  // Inactive by default on <= large.
  skel
  .on('+large', function() {
    $sidebar.addClass('inactive');
  })
  .on('-large !large', function() {
    $sidebar.removeClass('inactive');
  });
```

To this;

```
// Sidebar.
var $sidebar = $('#sidebar'),
$sidebar_inner = $sidebar.children('.inner');

  // Inactive by default on <= large.
  skel
  .on('-large !large', function() {
    $sidebar.addClass('inactive');
  })
  .on('+large', function() {
    $sidebar.addClass('inactive');
  });
```

In main.js file.

It is working the way i want but only on locally; when i upload it, it works as before.

What should i do? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
skel
  .on('+large', function() {
    $sidebar.removeClass('inactive');
  })
  .on('-large !large', function() {
    $sidebar.addClass('inactive');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better now than never. Just change

```
breakpoints.on('<=large', function() {
    $sidebar.addClass('inactive');
});

        breakpoints.on('>large', function() {
    $sidebar.removeClass('inactive');
});
```

to

```
breakpoints.on('<=large', function() {
    $sidebar.removeClass('inactive');
});

breakpoints.on('>large', function() {
    $sidebar.addClass('inactive');
});
```